# Javascript How to get nearest hour of current time and add additional hour

Tags: javascript

I want to get the nearest hour of the current time and then add an additional hour.

This is what I got so far:

```
let nearest_hour = new Date(Math.ceil(new Date().getTime() / 900000) * 900000)
```

when the time for example is 14:51, this gives me 15:00. So far so good, but how can I add one hour to this, so that instead of 15:00 it would return 16:00 ?

Comment: why ` / 900000 ` ? that is not the conversion rate between milliseconds and hours but rather to the nearest 15 minutes marks

Comment: st80 u can mark the person as correct.. that's the answer

Comment: what do you expect for 14:15?    15:00, or 16:00 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
new Date(Math.ceil(Date.now() / 3600000 + 1) * 3600000)
```

Comment: oh.. yea this is the complete answer :D

Comment: `Date.now()` is preferable to `new Date().getTime()` - it directly returns epoch milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

To round to the *nearest* hour, per the question, use `Math.round`, and then add one to get the desired result:

```
 const nearest = new Date(3600000 * (1 + Math.round(Date.now() / 3600000)));
```

explanation:

```
let hour = Date.now() / 3600000;    // hours since the epoch
let whole_hour = Math.round(hour);  // rounded up or down
let next_hour = 1 + whole_hour;     // plus one, per question
let millis = 3600000 * next_hour;   // convert back to milliseconds
const nearest = new Date(millis);   // convert to Date object
```